# How can I change my php server settings so that writing $x[y] == $x['y']?

Tags: php, variables, settings

As said in the title:

How can I change my php server settings so that writing $x[y] == $x['y']?

edit:

And no I wasn't lazy, I was handed a bunch of code that was written like this.

Comment: Never, ever, ever do that. Unquoted entities are constants.

Comment: there is no reason to downvote, the question is legit in the PHP environment, which actually allows this behaviour

Comment: Write your own PHP derivative language where constants are strings? Or don't be so lazy that typing a couple `'` causes you pain.

Comment: @ElzoValugi: Only if you're flying blind. Additionally the OP has not asked what she/he wanted to know which could have clarified the issue.

Comment: @hakre Downvoting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Comment: @ElzoValugi: What do you want to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclear what you mean...

```
$x[y]
```

and

```
$x['y']
```

is nothing to do with server settings

It's all about not having erroneous code.

```
$x[y]
```

is looking to find a constant called y and if that constant doesn't exist, it warns you and tries again assuming that you mistyped and that y is a string with a value 'y' (the equivalent of)

```
$x['y']
```

Fix your code and use 'y' so that PHP doesn't have to guess what you mean, or issue warnings to tell you that you've done something wrong

Comment: Okey, guys. Thank you for clarifying it to me, I recieved a bunch of code written like that by a senior programmer so I'm just checking if I'm crazy or. ..

Answer (score 4):

there is no server setting that does that. What Cyclone is saying is correct.

**Why is $foo[bar] wrong?**

Always use quotes around a string literal array index. For example, $foo['bar'] is correct, while $foo[bar] is not. But why? It is common to encounter this kind of syntax in old scripts:

```
<?php
$foo[bar] = 'enemy';
echo $foo[bar];
// etc
?>
```

This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an undefined constant (bar) rather than a string ('bar' - notice the quotes). PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

[Source](http://no.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: $foo[bar] isn't wrong if you're trying to access the constant bar.

Comment: that is what I'm saying, read to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use that method when writing strings, when PHP will not be looking for a constant. For example, its okay to write something like this:

```
echo "Hello $row[first_name] $row[last_name]!";
```

But any other time you are reffering to an array index, always use quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. You would have to define y as a constant, of value 'y'.
eg

```
define('y','y');
```

And we know that is silly.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to do this thing.

You are creating erroneous code.T

here is no server setting for that.

Even if you use `define('y','y');`  that is not a standard. Change and clean your code instead of going for such things.